# Existing Ecommerce plugins with Custom Post Types

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce, woocommerce-offtopic

I am developing a solution which is selling a service (can not be categorized as product) I have developed custom post types and taxonomies but I do not want to re-invent the wheel by adding payment gateways just for this purpose. Is there any way I can customize the "Product" post type in any existing ecommerce plugin available.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Your title and tags mention multiple plugins, your question just one. Please clarify your question.

Comment: In your question you are asking about customizing the post type (and your title references custom post types), but the answer you've selected is how to add a new product type to WooCommerce. If that is what you were looking for you should revise your question so that it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download en use WooCommerce with buildin payment gateways

You can add a product type with something like:

```
function my_add_product_type( $types ) {
    return $types["service"] = "Service";
}
add_filter( "product_type_selector", "my_add_product_type" );
```

Comment: How can remove/disable the product type field?

Comment: This is the correct code for adding a "product" type. I'd also point out that a "Service" is probably just a simple, virtual product. Unless you are planning to majorly modify the behavior of a simple product there probably isn't a need to create a new product type.

Comment: Simple product indeed could do the job. I don't recommend to completely remove the dropdown, you do can set "service" as the only product type: `return array( "Service" );`

Answer (score 3):

If you're post type is called 'product' then if you remove the code that registers your post type, and activate, say WooCommerce, the plugin should recognize the posts. You would need to configure some of the meta fields, however.

Following up on your comment, WooCommerce registers the `product` post type with the following pertinent code:

```
if ( post_type_exists('product') )
    return;

do_action( 'woocommerce_register_post_type' );

$permalinks        = get_option( 'woocommerce_permalinks' );
$product_permalink = empty( $permalinks['product_base'] ) ? _x( 'product', 'slug', 'woocommerce' ) : $permalinks['product_base'];

register_post_type( "product",
    apply_filters( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                    'name'                  => __( 'Products', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'singular_name'         => __( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'menu_name'             => _x( 'Products', 'Admin menu name', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'add_new'               => __( 'Add Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'edit'                  => __( 'Edit', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'new_item'              => __( 'New Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'view'                  => __( 'View Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'view_item'             => __( 'View Product', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'search_items'          => __( 'Search Products', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'not_found'             => __( 'No Products found', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Products found in trash', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'parent'                => __( 'Parent Product', 'woocommerce' )
                ),
            'description'           => __( 'This is where you can add new products to your store.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'capability_type'       => 'product',
            'map_meta_cap'          => true,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'hierarchical'          => false, // Hierarchical causes memory issues - WP loads all records!
            'rewrite'               => $product_permalink ? array( 'slug' => untrailingslashit( $product_permalink ), 'with_front' => false, 'feeds' => true ) : false,
            'query_var'             => true,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
            'has_archive'           => ( $shop_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) && get_page( $shop_page_id ) ? get_page_uri( $shop_page_id ) : 'shop',
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => true
        )
    )
);
```

You will note that all the args for `register_post_type` are open to filtering via the `woocommerce_register_post_type_product` filter.

Therefore if you wanted to change all the backend labels to say Services you could do the following:

```
function wpa_137268( $args ){
    $args['labels'] = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Services' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Service' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Services', 'Admin menu name' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add Service' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Service' ),
        'edit'                  => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Service' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Service' ),
        'view'                  => __( 'View Service' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Service' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Services' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No Services found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Services found in trash' ),
        'parent'                => __( 'Parent Service' )
    );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'wpa_137268' );
```

You can extrapolate from there to change anything else you are interested in changing.

Comment: My problem is different.I want to change the custom post types used by WooCommerce to say a post type called "Services". Is there any way we can do that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand. I still don't know exactly what you want to change, but you can change a lot about the product post type as Woo has a filter for all the args that go into the `register_post_type`. I will edit my answer.